# Mostrar slider ao carregar em foto

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, imagem, slider

Boa Tarde, tenho 4 imagens no meu website feito em bootstrap que correspondem a 4 categorias  e gostaria que ao carregar nelas me aparecesse um slider simples com as fotos todas de cada categoria. Como fazer?

Obrigado

Comment: Não vamos fazer para você. Mas você pode começar a desenvolver essa página e depois você pode vir aqui e perguntar suas dúvidas e dificuldades. Já começou a fazer alguma coisa ? Qual sua linguagem `server-side` ?

Comment: O que eu queria era só pegar num slider feito em jquery por exemplo e em vez de ele aparecer na página estático queria que só aparecesse quando clicava na imagem da categoria. Mas não sei por onde começar. Basicamente era isto: http://foobox.fooshowcase.com/hidden-gallery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode seguir esse exemplo.Ele está disponível nesse 
[Bootstrap Carousel Plugin](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp). Ele já está pronto para o uso, tendo apenas que fazer pequenas modificações como indicar onde estão as suas imagens que serão exibidas!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!